# Using gulp to override only files that already exist is the destination directory

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm setting up a workflow to improve the process of linting, compiling, and distributing design files in a large application. I'd love to use gulp for this workflow but doing so requires a sort of sync-down process, making sure that files on the local directory first mirror the state of the files in the production (remote) directory.

I don't want to pull the entire state of the remote directory, as it includes thousands of automatically generated files that don't need to exist locally. How can I check my destination to confirm a filename match before pulling a new version from the remote server? I don't care which file is more recent, it's fine to simply overwrite everything that has a match in path and filename.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to pull files that you already have in the destination, I would do:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gt = require('through-gulp');
var read = require('gulp-read');

var remote_source_dir = "src/"; // must end with /

gulp.src('destination/**/*', {read:false})
  .pipe(gt(function(vinyl,enc,cb) {
    vinyl.path = remote_source_dir + vinyl.relative;
    vinyl.base = remote_source_dir;
    cb(null, vinyl);
  }))
  .pipe(read())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("destination"));
```

Background: Gulp streams use "vinyl" objects. They basically contain the file path and the file contents. Read more [here](https://medium.com/@contrahacks/gulp-3828e8126466#835b).

The `gulp.src()` call gets all the filenames in destination that we want to update. We set read to false so as not to read the actual contents of the files in the destination directory (since we want the contents to be actually read from the source directory).

The `gt()` creates a transform stream, and every vinyl object is passed through the given function. The function adjusts the path and the base for the file so that they point to the (remote) source directory instead. The `cb(null, vinyl);` finally reports the result of the transformation.

Then, `read()` then transforms the vinyl that now contain the correct source filename by reading the file contents into the vinyl object.

Finally `gulp.dest()` writes the files to the given destination directory.

TIP: For testing, you can change the `"destination"` argument to the `gulp.dest()` function to something else, e.g. `"destination2"` and it will output the copied files to a different directory. Then you can compare the destination and destination2 directories to verify correct operation.

Note: If some file in the destination directory does NOT exist in the source directory, the script will fail. If you want to exclude certain files in the destination directory from copying, you can use for example [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter), between `gulp.src()` and `gt()`. Alternatively you can check the filename programmatically in the `gt()` transform stream and call just `cb()` instead of `cb(null, vinyl)` for files you want to skip.